# Why does my code not run correct with arr10 but work fine with arr9?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, min, minimum

To get the minimum value in an array, I made the method minValue

```java
public int minValue() {
    int smallestVal = 0; //field
    
    if (intArray.length == 0) { //if array is empty, return 0
        return 0;
    }
    
    int a = intArray[0]; //field
    
    for (int i : intArray) {
        if (i > a) {
            smallestVal = a;
        }
        else {
            a = i;
        }
    }

    return smallestVal; //returns the smallest value
}
```

Tested it in a main method with `arr9 = { 1, 2, -1, 40, 1, 40, 0, 0, -3, 2, 2, -2, -5, 0, 1, -4, -5 }`
and `arr10 = { 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 5, -3, 4, -1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 4, 5, -5 }`

For arr9, it returns -5 but for arr10 it returns -3 instead of -5.
Is there something I need to change in my code?

Comment: if you take smallest value as 0 at first, if the array doesn't contain zero and all greater than zero elements, smallest value will still result as 0, hence taking the first value from array as smallest before loop is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work with the second array is because it will never set `smallestVal` when the smallest value is the last location in the array.

There is no need for your variable `a` here. Replace it with this:

```
int smallestVal = intArray[0]; //field
for (int i : intArray){
       if (i < smallestVal){
           smallestVal = i;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i > a) {
    smallestVal = a;
}
else {
    a = i;
}
```

This sets `a` to the value of `i` if `i` is smaller or equal `a` and sets `smallestVal` to the value of `a` if `i` is greater than `a`. In the case that `i` is never greater than `a` after `a` got updated `smalledtVal` will not be updated to the smallest value. I'd suggest getting rid of `smallestVal` and just returning `a` as `a` should always contain the smallest value. That being said `a` should probably be named `smallestVal` as it's a more descriptive name.